# How to force Jenkins/Hudson to refresh Upstream and Downstream dependencies

Tags: maven, jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins

I have looked through SO and found a number of questions similar to this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106205/how-to-manually-specify-or-refresh-jenkins-upstream-and-downstream-dependencies?rq=1

The original poster of the question above did not make clear what type of jobs he was running.

We have all our Jenkins jobs configured as maven jobs (we use maven 3). Sometimes, the POMs of a particular modules have dependency changes that either add new dependencies or remove them. We are not seeing Jenkins reflect this change of dependencies in the list of Upstream or Downstream projects.

Is there a way to force Jenkins to rebuild the upstream/downstream projects for a specific job?

To add some minor value if somebody is reading this and the question remains unanswered:

It is possible to force Jenkins to rebuild the dependency map by removing the project and adding it back in to Jenkins. I would prefer to simply click something to force Jenkins to rebuild the dependency map for this job though.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question?

Comment: Only the workaround I mentioned in my edit: It is possible to force Jenkins to rebuild the dependency map by removing the project and adding it back in to Jenkins. I would prefer to simply click something to force Jenkins to rebuild the dependency map for this job though.